# ASP.NET Core - How to validate string date input as YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a string date input in ASP.NET Core:

DTO:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Implementation:

```
var studentUser = new Student()
{
    FirstName = dto.FirstName,
    LastName = dto.LastName,
    BirthDate = dto.BirthDate
};
```

As I said BirthDate is string. I am to insert the above into DB.

How do I validate and format to ensure that the user only add BirthDate as YYYY-MM-DD only?

Comment: Post your attempted code.

Comment: `<input type='date'>` and the web browser makes the job

Comment: Your DTO should be using DateTime (or DateTime?) instead of string.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ASP.NET+date+validation

Comment: If you use string to input, i think you can use `Regular expression`, But i don't think it is a good method, I suggest to use DateTime type as input.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this decorator above the BirthDate

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
```